# Sinatra OPTIONS HTTP Verb

Tags: sinatra

Does Sinatra support the OPTIONS HTTP verb? Something like:

```
options '/' do
  response.headers["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = "*"
  response.headers["Access-Control-Allow-Methods"] = "POST"

  halt 200
end
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

After a bit of hacking I managed to get it working using:

```
before do
  if request.request_method == 'OPTIONS'
    response.headers["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = "*"
    response.headers["Access-Control-Allow-Methods"] = "POST"

    halt 200
  end
end
```

**Edit:**

After some more looking around on this issue, I realized that a PULL request is up on GitHub for the addition of the `OPTIONS` verb (https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/pull/129). I took the solution and hacked it in using the following snippet:

```
configure do
  class << Sinatra::Base
    def options(path, opts={}, &block)
      route 'OPTIONS', path, opts, &block
    end
  end
  Sinatra::Delegator.delegate :options
end
```

Now I can simply use:

```
options '/' do
  ...
end
```

**Edit:**

The pull request should be merged. No more need for the hack.

Comment: If you are reading this, please check [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10195704/316700), now Sinatra implements the `options` _method_ out-of-the-box.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, already does it [Sinatra Routes documentation](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Routes)

Answer (score 2):

No it does not. If you look at the code on [GitHub](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/master/lib/sinatra/base.rb#L1008) you can see where the HTTP verbs are defined, and `options` is not one of them.

Comment: @KevinSylvestre Given that it appears that the existing route verbs are implemented as class methods on Sinatra::Base (see the link that Jergason gave) you should just be able to define your own: `def Sinatra::Base.options(path,opts={},&bk); route 'OPTIONS', path, opts, &bk end` (untested).

Comment: @Phrogz Thanks! That snippet helped me out in figuring out how to patch it in. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

the answer is, simply, yes! (look under Routes in the read me http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html)