# jquery.form and cross-domain requests

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-plugins, cross-domain

I'm having a hard time trying to make [jquery.form](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) with a cross-domain request. I'm having issues with Firefox and Chrome (didn't even try IE yet).

Explanation: my whole site is located inside http://www.mysite.com. However, my contact form is on another server, referenced by http://contact.mysite.com . I thought that putting it on a subdomain would sidestep the issues regarding cross-domain requests, but apparently it didn't. http://contact.mysite.com is implemented in [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com/).

My javascript setup is nothing fancy. The form's action points to http://contact.mysite.com and the method is POST:

```
<form id="contact" action="http://contact.mysite.com/" method="post">
```

jquery.form is configured with an [ajaxForm](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#ajaxForm) call:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#contact').ajaxForm({
    success: function() { $('#success').fadeIn("slow"); },
    error: function() {  $('#error').fadeIn("slow"); }
  });

});
```

The first problem I encountered was with Firefox 3.5 - apparently it sends an OPTIONS request expecting an specific answer from the server. I used [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4351904/sinatra-options-http-verb) to configure my Sinatra app so it did what was expected (it seems that more recent versions of sinatra include an options verb):

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'
require 'pony'

# patch sinatra so it handles options requests - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4351904/sinatra-options-http-verb
configure do
  class << Sinatra::Base
    def options(path, opts={}, &block)
      route 'OPTIONS', path, opts, &block
    end
  end
  Sinatra::Delegator.delegate :options
end

# respond to options requests so that firefox can do cross-domain ajax requests
options '/' do
  response['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
  response['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'POST'
  response['Access-Control-Max-Age'] = '2592000'
end

post '/' do
  # use Pony to send an email
  Pony.mail(...)
end
```

With jquery 1.4.3, I saw on firebug an OPTIONS request followed by a POST request (status 200. The email was sent). With jquery 1.3.2 or 1.5, only the OPTIONS request was shown (the email was not sent).

Nevertheless, the `error` callback is always fired with all versions of jquery I tried. I traced that down to the `$.ajax(...)` call, so I'm not sure of whether this problem comes from jquery.form or jquery itself.

I tried logging out the information coming from the error:

```
$('#contact').ajaxForm({
  success: function() { $('#success').fadeIn("slow"); },
  error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.log(jqXHR.status);
    console.log(jqXHR.statusText);
  }
});
```

Output on jquery 1.4.3 (after the OPTIONS & POST requests are sent, both with status 200):

```
0
(empty string)
```

Output on jquery 1.5 (after OPTIONS returns with a 200 status; POST is never sent)

```
302
error
```

I'm really lost here.

- Is there a plugin that handles this?
- Am I missing something somewhere?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

AJAX requests cannot be executed cross-domain (**UPD:** not true anymore, all modern browsers support [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)), but you can use JSONP instead. Although JSONP works cross-domain, it can't be used for POST requests, and you'll need to change you form's method to `get` and use this:

```
$('#contact').ajaxForm({
  success: function() { $('#success').fadeIn("slow"); },
  error: function() {  $('#error').fadeIn("slow"); },
  dataType: 'jsonp'
});
```

The solution above relies on your server responding with a valid jsonp response, otherwise `success` handler won't be executed. e.g: `response.write(request.callback + '(' + result.to_json + ')')`

---

Latest versions of jQuery can serialize forms without the `ajaxForm` plugin. If you don't need file uploads you can use this:

```
$('form').submit(function() {
  var url = $(this).attr('action')
  var params = $(this).serialize()
  $.getJSON(url + '?' + params + "&callback=?", function(data) {
    // success
  })
  return false
});
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I'm still trying to wrap my head around this jsonp business. One question thought: $.ajax seems to be able to do jsonp requests (or so it says in the documentation, I'm still not sure of how it works). Since jquery.form uses $.ajax internally, wouldn't it be able to use jsonp too?

Comment: You know what, I looked at the $.ajaxForm source and I think it can do it. I can't try the example now, but I hope it works.

Comment: See my new update, I tested and it works fine if you return a valid json response from your server.

Comment: Hi Alexeley, thanks for your update. Will try on my server this evening. One question though - you mention something about jsonp only working with GET requests. Is that true? I didn't find any references on that.

Comment: JSONP works by adding a <script src=> element to the DOM, with the external url as the src target. It's a simple script inclusion, which is always a GET request. More info here: http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/107136.aspx

Comment: Your solution works beautifully. I ended up ditching jquery.form and using getJSON directly (you need to replace the `+ '/' +` by `+ '?' +` though; I've changed that in your answer)

Comment: What if you DO need this for file uploads?  Having the same issue, but with a form where you upload a file.  Can't seem to get it to work cross-domain.

Comment: @Whatevo: If you have control over the receiving server you can set a special header allowing cross-domain requests, and `$.ajaxForm` should be able to work. http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/ and http://www.kendoui.com/blogs/teamblog/posts/11-10-03/using_cors_with_all_modern_browsers.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I think JSONP the only AJAX request which can cross domain.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#JSONP

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is not a complete answer, but at least gives me a hint. I'll investigate JSONP.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a local proxy URL to perform the request as servers can generally make cross-domain calls using something like HttpRequest or cURL. So basically you make a call using ajax to a URL on the local domain and then forward the request to the cross-domain URL and pass the response from the HttpRequest/cURL back to the browser in the response from the local domain.

Comment: That is not an option with my current setup. The server serving the main app is out of my control. Thanks for your answer anyway.

Answer (score 1):

After lots of fighting, I finally ended up conquering this, with the help of Alexey. Here's my solution, for now:

Javascript (using jquery directly, without jquery.form):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#contact').submit(function() {
    $('#success').fadeOut("slow");
    $('#bademail').fadeOut("slow");

    var url = $(this).attr('action')
    var params = $(this).serialize()
    $.getJSON(url + '?' + params + "&callback=?", function(data) {
      if(data == true) { // success
        $('#success').fadeIn("slow");
        $('#contact')[0].reset();
      } else { // error
        $('#bademail').fadeIn("slow");
      }
    });

    return false;
  });
});
```

With Sinatra, I used the [sinatra-jsonp gem](https://github.com/shtirlic/sinatra-jsonp). I make the get action return "true" or "false" depending on whether the emails can be sent or not (for example, for an invalid email address).

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'
require 'sinatra/jsonp'
require 'pony'


get '/' do

  # check for blanks, etc
  return jsonp false unless fields_valid(params)

  Pony.mail(
    ...
  )

  return jsonp true

end
```