# Communication by JSFIDDLE with PHP code and database on server

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want communication by **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net)** (jQuery AJAX call => url:...) with PHP code in my server but have following error.

> An error has occured:
>  [object Object]
>  error

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/mmJNq/

what do i do?

```
$('.eghamat').live('keyup', function () {
    var $this = $(this),
        $div = $this.closest('div.bg_units'),
        bu_num = '.' + $div.attr('class').split(" ")[1];
    var dataObj = $(this).closest('form').serialize();
    //alert(dataObj);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: 'json',
            url: 'http://binboy.gigfa.com/admin/tour_foreign/auto_complete',
            //url: 'auto_complete',
            data: dataObj,
            cache: false,
            success: function (data) {
                //alert(bu_num);
                var id_name = $(bu_num + ' .list_autobox_hotel').attr('id');
                $(bu_num + ' .list_autobox_hotel').show().html('');
                if (data == 0) {
                    $(bu_num + ' .list_autobox_hotel').show().html('<p><b>there is no</b></p>');
                } else {
                    $.each(data, function (index, value) {
                        $('<p id="' + value.name + '">' + value.name + '</p>').appendTo('.list_autobox_hotel');
                    });
                }
            },
            "error": function (x, y, z) {
                // callback to run if an error occurs
                alert("An error has occured:\n" + x + "\n" + y + "\n" + z);
            }
        });
});
```

Comment: You can't use AJAX for cross domain requests.

Comment: @Shadow +1. Just write 'The Answer'

Comment: See this: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5066213/jquery-form-and-cross-domain-requests/5075858#5075858](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5066213/jquery-form-and-cross-domain-requests/5075858#5075858)