# Sinatra access-control-allow-origin for sinatra public folder

Tags: html, sinatra

How do I set up Sinatra so that static files in the public folder
are returned with the response Access-Control-Allow-Origin = "*" ?

Answer (score 17):

Have a look at this question here: [Sinatra OPTIONS HTTP Verb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4351904/sinatra-options-http-verb). It's implemented in sinatra now so you don't have to hack around it.

If that doesn't help take a look at this blog post: [Cross Origin Resource Sharing with Sinatra](http://britg.com/2009/12/29/cross-origin-resource-sharing-with-sinatra/), and its repo at github: [sinatra-corss_origin](https://github.com/britg/sinatra-cross_origin)

Although the simplest way to do it should work just by adding this:

```
response['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = 'http://whatever.org'
```

before the return value in your route.

Comment: I'm not using `response` but `headers`: `headers( "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" => "*" )`

Comment: See [sinatra-cors](https://github.com/jdesrosiers/sinatra-cors) for a more up-to-date gem.

Comment: within the `get '/' do`  `<new line>` `response['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'` `<new line>` `"asdf"` `<new line>` `end`

Answer (score 7):

```
get '/foo' do
  headers 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' => 'http://example.com'
  'hello world'
end
```

There's also a nice extension for cross origin sharing:

https://github.com/britg/sinatra-cross_origin

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'sinatra/cross_origin'

# To enable cross origin requests for all routes:
configure do
  enable :cross_origin
end

# To only enable cross origin requests for certain routes:
get '/cross_origin' do
  cross_origin
  "This is available to cross-origin javascripts"
end
```

Comment: Does the gem work? I tried, and I couldn't get the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header to show up until I explicitly added it within my response method as in the answer by @daddz

Answer (score 3):

I did this on a server side, my file was called server.rb:

```
before do
   content_type :json    
   headers 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' => '*', 
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' => ['OPTIONS', 'GET', 'POST']  
end
```

Comment: Thank you. I got away with just the first bit, `headers "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" => "*"`, to allow a GET request. Did not try other verbs.

Answer (score 0):

This setup works for me:

**Gemfile:**

```
# Gemfile
gem 'sinatra'
gem 'sinatra-cross_origin'
```

**Sinatra App:**

```
# app.rb
require 'sinatra'
require 'sinatra/cross_origin'
class MyApp < Sinatra::Base
  set :bind, '0.0.0.0'
  configure do
    #This is enable cross on the server
    enable :cross_origin
  end

  #This before blocks gets invoked on every request and
  #the (*) mark tells your server that share the resource with anyone, 
  #if you want to share it with specific domain you can mention the domain/s 
  #by removing the asterisk sign.

  before do
    response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
  end

  # routes...
  options "*" do
    response.headers["Allow"] = "GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"
    response.headers["Access-Control-Allow-Headers"] = "Authorization, 
        Content-Type, Accept, X-User-Email, X-Auth-Token"
    response.headers["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = "*"
    200
  end
end
```

The options block described above sends a 200 response to the preflight request sent by the browser. Then the browser makes the CORS request. In response to this request, the server sends Access-Control-Allow-Origin = * in response headers.

If we want only a specific domain to access the resources:

```
before do
  response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = 'http://example.com'
end
```

Answer (score -1):

this solution works for me and is based on an answer on a similar question  [How to add "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" headers to API Response in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42454418/how-to-add-access-control-allow-origin-headers-to-api-response-in-ruby)

```
get '/' do
  response['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
  "asdf"  # return "asdf" 
end
```