# POST JSON response to HTTP request in Ruby

Tags: ruby, json, heroku

I'm running a Ruby app on Heroku. The app returns a JSON which is accessible when I go to the debugger of my browser. The JSON response is of the following template:

```
rates = {
    "Aluminium" => price[1],
    "Copper" => price_cu[1],
    "Lead" => price_pb[1],
    "Nickel" => price_ni[1],
    "Tin" => price_sn[1],
    "Zinc" => price_zn[1],
}
```

Sample response:

```
{
    "Aluminium":"1765.50",
    "Copper":"7379.00",
    "Lead":"2175.00",
    "Nickel":"14590.00",
    "Tin":"22375.00",
    "Zinc":"2067.00"
}
```

the code i wrote to achieve this is:

Test.rb

```
class FooRunner
    def self.run!
        #calculations_for_rates
        rates.to_json
    end
if __FILE__ == $0
    puts FooRunner.run!
end
```

app.rb

```
require 'sinatra'
require './test.rb'

result = FooRunner.run!
File.open('output.json','w') do |f|
        f.write result
end

content_type :json
result
```

When I try to access this link using

```
$.getJSON('app-url',function(data){
    console.log(data);
});
```

it gives me an error saying

`No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

Is there a way for me to directly access the JSON response by writing the JSON to the HTTP response?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sinatra access-control-allow-origin for sinatra public folder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7109971/sinatra-access-control-allow-origin-for-sinatra-public-folder)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I am guessing that the page you are making the `get` request from is not served up by Sinatra. You can add the header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` to that request to make it work.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7111282/509710) shows how to do it by either using `response['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = *` or `headers( "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" => "*" )`

That answer also lists [this blog post](http://britg.com/2009/12/29/cross-origin-resource-sharing-with-sinatra/) as a reference to Cross Origin Resource Sharing in Sinatra.