# Http get response blank page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ruby

I am trying to create  light Angularjs app. I am running api server through irb cli and it is running on port 4567. When i run bundle exec ruby.rb I can confirm that there is data on the address: http://localhost:4567/api/v1/companies:

```
[
  {"id": "1",
   "name": "A"
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "B",
  } 
]
```

I have tried with this code (hello.js):

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
        $scope.company=[];
      $http.get("http://localhost:4567/api/v1/companies")
      /*$http.get("http://localhost/fake.json")*/
    .then(function(response) {
        $scope.company = response.data;

    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Hello AngularJS</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="hello.js"></script>
    </head>

        <body>
            <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl">
            <ul>
                    <li ng-repeat="x in company">
                        {{ 'name: ' + x.name + ',  id:' + x.id }}
                    </li>
            </ul>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

The thing is, if I change the url to the "http://localhost/fake.json" as commented I see the data response clear. But if I use the local web server I can not see anything. Is there some kind of permissions problem or something else.

Comment: Do you get an error in the console? Or in your backend service logs,

Comment: "I am running api server through irb cli" - what do you mean? Since this is tagged ruby-on-rails I´m guessing you are using Rails. You start the rails server with the `bin/rails server` command not through irb.

Comment: please see what console has to say about the error and I am not sure but if you see the data in the console we can think of running a digest cycle. But before that see if you have no error in the console in the scenario where you do not see any data on the page.

Comment: I did it in Ruby but on Sinatra platform, I have removed the tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was sinatra-access-control-allow-origin, I found the solution on: [Sinatra access-control-allow-origin for sinatra public folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7109971/sinatra-access-control-allow-origin-for-sinatra-public-folder/47317965#47317965)

Answer (score 0):

use `success` callback instead of `then` see this [document](https://www.peterbe.com/plog/promises-with-$http)

```
$scope.company=[];
      $http.get("http://localhost:4567/api/v1/companies")
      /*$http.get("http://localhost/fake.json")*/
    .success(function(response) {
        $scope.company = response.data;// response or response.data is depend your service response    
    }).error(function(errorStatus)
    {
      //code
    });
```