# Sinatra app on Heroku responds with Forbidden if I follow links

Tags: ruby, heroku, sinatra, puma

I've created a little Sinatra app and use Puma to run it. I've deployed my app to Heroku and everything works fine, but if I follow an external link to my app, I get the response `Forbidden`. Where does this come from?

The app only defines one HTTP method:

```
require 'sinatra'

get '/' do
  headers 'Content-Type' => 'application/json'
  body 'Hello World'
end
```

For example following https://contactsampleprovider.herokuapp.com/ will result in `Forbidden`, but entering the URL manually in the browser works fine.

If I leave out the `headers`-call, everything works as expected.

Comment: If that is real user data, please remove it asap.

Comment: @yez: No of course not. The whole purpose of the app is to randomly generate test data.

Comment: Ok that's great news.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a feature of Rack protection that seems to be enabled automatically if you set the content type to JSON. It can be disabled by

```
set :protection, :except => [:json_csrf]
```

as described for example in this question on [Sinatra and Rack protection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10509774/sinatra-and-rack-protection-setting).