# How to turn off " Rack::Protection::JsonCsrf"?

Tags: ruby, heroku, sinatra, csrf

In my heroku logs I see this:

```
 WARN -- : attack prevented by Rack::Protection::JsonCsrf
```

I know  the reason of why it appears there and I want to turn off that protection mechanism. How?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/16125324/271475

Answer (score 1):

Apply this in an appropriate location such as `configu.ru`:

```
configure do
  set :protection, :except => [:json_csrf]
end
```