# Where do you set the access control headers in Padrino

Tags: html, ruby, access-control, padrino

In Ruby on Rails you can place the access control headers in the Application Controller. What about Padrino? where do you place them? I've tried placing them in the method of a Controller I need to use different headers and inside app.rb, but it doesn't workout... any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps the answer to this question could help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4351904/sinatra-options-http-verb

Answer (score 0):

As Nikhil mentioned it, setting the response headers yourself is a great way of doing it and being in control of what's happening.

If you put them on a before block in app.rb they will apply to the every route in your app which I guess is what you're trying to achieve here.

Just be careful on which permissions you grant. I find [this MDN guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#The_HTTP_response_headers) a great resource for CORS headers.